# Is there a Haskell equivalent to Python's `shelve` for transparent persistence?

Tags: python, haskell, persistence, shelve

Python has this magical `shelve` which is like a `dict` except it's automatically backed by a file. It allows you to persist a large data structure between runs of a program. The really amazing thing is that it doesn't even load the whole thing from disk each time you run but waits for you to ask for a key and then gives you just that key's value.

So, the obvious question: Can Haskell compete?

Comment: Haskell programmers rarely want things, especially I/O things like saving and loading, to happen transparently (i.e. automagically). Idiomatic Haskell code explicates I/O. There are powerful file-backed stores; `acid-state` jumps to mind. But none are "magical," for many reasons. (Among other things, idiomatic Haskell data structures are often infinite!)

Comment: Not just infinite, but immutable! The value of a transparent write-through cache to disk seems pretty pale when writes aren't allowed.

Answer (score 3):

[Persistent](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent) along with one of it's more general backends like [map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-map), [refs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-refs), [protobuf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-protobuf), or [cereal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-cereal)?

Comment: None of the "backends" you link to are actually backends. Two aren't related to `persistent`; the others are helpers (and out of date). Michael may be interested in `persistent-sqlite` though.

Comment: I played with Persistent and the thing I don't like is that you have to define a SQL table structure though I think with more effort I think you could make a table with columns that look like an Aeson Value. However, since my use case is read heavy, write rarely, I find that Cerial and Map meet my needs.